# Efficiently converting JavaScript key and value arrays to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to turn two JavaScript arrays into a list of objects. One of the input arrays represents the keys of the output object and the other contains its values (alongside some other information, not relevant to this question).

Example data:

```
let theKeys = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'city'];
let theValues = [{data: [['John', 'Smith', 'New York'],
                         ['Mike', 'Doe', 'Chicago'],
                         ...
                        ],
                 otherStuff: ...}
                ];
```

Desired output for above:

```
output = [{
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Smith',
            city: 'New York'
          },
          {
            firstName: 'Mike',
            lastName: 'Doe',
            city: 'Chicago',
          },
          ...
         ]
```

(This is just an example, my actual data comes from REST responses and can vary in content and length. I'm working with a Vue app that displays tabular data.)

My existing code, below, works for small amounts of data but makes all browsers crash or hang for larger amounts of data.

```
return this.theValues.flatMap(results => {
  let jsonified = [];

  for (let v = 0; v < results.theValues.length; v++) {
    let singleJson = {}; 

    for (let k = 0; k < this.theKeys.length; k++) {
      let key = this.theKeys[k];
      singleJson[key] = results.data[v][k];
    }

    jsonified.push(singleJson);
  }

  return jsonified;
});
```

For as few as a couple thousand results, this takes minutes to run. How can I make it faster? Is there some operation I'm missing that will allow me to avoid the nested for loop?

Comment: What is the size of `this.theValue`, is it also a computed property in vue?

Comment: It varies. If it's, like, seven, or 18, everything is fine. If it's 20,429, I have problems. It's not computed, it's data returned from a remote server.

Comment: `results.data[v][k]` is your original response?

Comment: Also, `this.theKeys.length` seems strange...  `theValues` came from the same response, but not `theKeys`? I think your problem is not performance itself, but some racing condition in Vue

Comment: I send a request to the server, it sends a reply with some number of rows of data, and those rows are passed into the current component as a prop named `theValues`.

Comment: Well, you're right, `theKeys` does ultimately come from the response as well. It's computed based on the `otherStuff` part of the response. I was trying to simplify the example because I didn't think that part was relevant to the problem. But I can add more info if needed.

Comment: Can the `theValues` array contain multiple elements? (I mean `theValues`, not `theValues[0].data`)

Comment: @FZs I don't believe so.

Comment: 20K is so insignificantly, that it really seems __to me__ a racing issue in how you are passing props/data in your vue components. I'd try another approach to the problem. First, how are you using the mapped array? In a `v-for="let item of array"` loop? I'd suggest a method to get the table values in your HTML like `getData(i, j, key)` and then `return this.theValues[i][j][key]`

Comment: I see where you're coming from. The result of this is being used directly as the `items` prop for [a Vuetify `v-data-table` component](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/).

Comment: Another questions arise: 1. Do youhave control of the backend code? 2. Isn't there a server-side pagination? 3. The user will ever look at 20K entries, really? 4. Maybe, the problem isn't your loop, but the Vuetify trying to render 20K DOM rows? 

Comment: 1. yes 2. no 3. sadly, I am working on this because yes 4. I am more and more thinking this is the case (or, at least, the problem is not the loops/flatMap I originally suspected)

Comment: Include `console.time('test')` before the flatMap, and `console.timeEnd('test')` right before returning, to see the elapsed time.

Comment: If the problem resides within Vuetify, you can create a shallow copy of the 20K rows, to  code a pagination in-memory, this way Vuetify will never know you have got a 20K lenghty data

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I don't think it's the `v-data-table`. I added a few lines after the loop to create the results, so that all that logic still happens, but then I return a two-row hardcoded fake result set for Vuetify to use as input. The page still hangs for about four minutes while it does the loop (~30k rows, one column).

Comment: What about the console time test? How long it took?

Comment: Also, try storing `this.theKeys.length` in a const value, maybe `theKeys` is a vue computed property, with some getter/setter combination, and it may be processing something that it shouldn't

Comment: I narrowed it down to the call to `theValues`, which is really a prop of the component I'm working in. I replaced that with `Math.random()` and everything was lightning-fast. I think at this point it's time for a new question, more focused on Vue.

Comment: Good you narrowed it down to a vue behavior... later when you get an answer comment the link here

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes just FYI in case you're still interested, I did end up asking that follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65569982/how-can-i-repeatedly-access-a-vue-prop-without-tanking-performance

Comment: @SOLO Makes sense, `props` also have getters and setters defined by Vue, and not just the `computed` properties we have discussed before... As a rule, I always try to avoid  repeated access in getter/setter properties, just to keep things under control, you know, without running a "ghost" code (even if it is from Vue)... Glad you got it working, and by the way, happy new year :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way maybe to `.map` the values into key-value tuples and call `Object.fromEntries` on it:

```js
const theKeys = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'city'];
const theValues = [{
  data: [
    ['John', 'Smith', 'New York'],
    ['Mike', 'Doe', 'Chicago']
  ]
}];

console.log(
  theValues[0].data.map(e =>
    Object.fromEntries(e.map((e,i) => [theKeys[i], e]))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the inner loop if you hardcode the properties instead of looking at `theKeys`, but I doubt you'd want that. The only thing you don't really need is the `flatMap`. Most of the generic array methods aren't known for their speed, anyway (`forEach` is usually slower than a plain `for` loop, for example).

FWIW, this seems to perform fine:

```
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < theValues[0].data.length; i++) {
    let resultObj = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < theKeys.length; j++) {
        resultObj[theKeys[j]] = theValues[0].data[i][j];
    }
    result.push(resultObj);
}
```

I tested it with 11k items and it ran in about 5 miliseconds in Chrome. With 90k items, it still only took about 30ms.

Comment: This code produces the correct result in my app, but takes 255388ms to run on 29851 rows. Something weird is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can forego the `flatMap` which should save you some performance, just do everything with plain loop:

```
const result = []

for (const v of theValues) {
    for (const entry of v.data) {
        const obj = {}
        for (let i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
            obj[theKeys[i]] = entry[i]
        }
        result.push(obj)
    }
}
```

EDIT: micro-optimizations

```
const result = []
const keysLength = theKeys.length

for (let i = theValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const data = theValues[i].data
    for (let j = data.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        const entry = data[j]
        const obj = {}

        for (let k = keysLength - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            obj[theKeys[k]] = entry[k]
        }
        result.push(obj)
    }
}
```