# How can I repeatedly access a Vue prop without tanking performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on a Vue/Vuetify app that has a performance problem. I've created a custom component that wraps around [a standard Vuetify `v-data-table` component](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/). It works fine for small amounts of data, but giving it moderate to large amounts of data causes Firefox to hang and Chrome to crash.

Here's a slightly simplified version of my code:

```
<script>
import ...

export default {
  props: {
    theValues: Array,
    // other props
  },

  computed: {
    theKeys: function() {
      return this.schema.map(col => col.col);
    },

    schema: function() {
      return this.theValues[0].schema;
    },

    dataForDataTable: function() {
      console.time('test');

      let result = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < theValues[0].data.length; i++) {
        let resultObj = {};
        for (let j = 0; j < theKeys.length; j++) {
          // The "real" logic; this causes the browser to hang/crash
          // resultObj[theKeys[j]] = theValues[0].data[i][j];

          // Test operation to diagnose the problem
          resultObj[theKeys[j]] = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(99999));
        }
        result.push(resultObj);
      }

      console.timeEnd('test');
      // For ~30k rows, timer reports that:
      // Real values can take over 250,000 ms
      // Randomly generated fake values take only 7 ms

      return result;
    },

    // other computed
  },

  // other Vue stuff
</script>
```

And here's an example of what `theValues` actually looks like:

```
[
  {
    data: [
            [25389, 24890, 49021, ...] <-- 30,000 elements
          ],
    schema: [
              {
                col: "id_number",
                type: "integer"
              }
            ]
  }
]
```

The only meaningful difference I see between the fast code and the slow code is that the slow code accesses the prop `theValues` on each iteration whereas the fast code doesn't touch any complicated part of Vue. (It does use `theKeys`, but the performance doesn't change even if I create a local deep copy of `theKeys` inside the function.)

Based on this, it seems like the problem is **not** that the data table component can't handle the amount of data I'm sending, or that the nested loops are inherently too inefficient. My best guess is that reading from the prop so much is somehow slowing Vue itself down, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

But I do ultimately need to get the information from the prop into the table. What can I do to make this load at a reasonable speed?

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with accessing the prop.  Can you try pulling out the loop invariant part?  Before the loop, `const thePropData = theValues[0].data;`, then in the loop `thePropData[i][j]`.  Does it make a difference?  (oh, and the iteration check `i < thePropData.length`)

Comment: Why you need to iterate over `theKeys` array? Why not use the reactivity offered by vuejs?

Comment: I had already tried something similar, pulling the call out of the inner loop, but not the outer loop. It didn't make a difference, which in hindsight is because in the simplified example there was only one column. Pulling it one level further up, out of the outer loop, did the trick. Post as an answer?

Comment: @Danizavtz sorry, I don't understand what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance problem is actually a symptom of your loop code rather than Vue. The most expensive data access is in your inner loop in `dataForDataTable()`:

```js
for (i...) {
  for (j...) {
    theValues[0].data[i][j]  // ~50 ms average (expensive)
  }
}

// => long hang for 32K items
```

An optimization would be to cache the array outside your loop, which dramatically improves the loop execution time and resolves the hang:

```js
const myData = theValues[0].data

for (i...) {
  for (j...) {
    myData[i][j]  // ~0.00145 ms average
  }
}

// => ~39 ms for 32K items
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/loop-performance-in-vue-forked-8esdh?file=/src/components/DataTable.vue)

Note the same result can be computed without loops, using JavaScript APIs. This affords readability and reduced lines of code at a slight performance cost (~1ms). Specifically, use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each value from `data` to an object property, obtained by [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on  `theKeys`:

```js
theValues[0].data
  .map(values => theKeys.reduce((obj,key,i) => {
    obj[key] = values[i]
    return obj
  }, {}))

// => ~40 ms for 32K items
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/loop-performance-in-vue-cc9bn?file=/src/components/DataTable.vue:668-842)

*Times above measured on 2016 MacBook Pro - 2.7GHz i7, Chrome 87. Codesandbox demos might show a vast variance from the above.*

Comment: can confirm that directly accessing `theValues[0]` in inner loops kills perf, but assigning it outside the loop is gold. not endorsing `reduce`, but that's personal preference.

Comment: I was really surprised to see this answer. How can simple array access (`theValues[0].data`) be that slow ?? But is seems you are right and it has something to do with Vue reactivity - you can get almost same result by leaving original `dataForDataTable` code and just `Object.freeze()` the source data (`sampleData.js` in your sandbox)

Answer (score 2):

### Tip 1

Original text:

> Accessing the prop (`data`) should not be an issue. Yes, `data` are reactive but reading it should be very efficient (Vue is just "making notes" that you are using that data for rendering)

Well it seems I was clearly wrong here...

Your component is getting data by prop but it is very probable that the data is reactive in parent component (coming from Vuex or stored in parent's `data`). Problem with Vue 2 reactivity system is it is based on [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and this system does not allow to intercept indexed array access (Vue is not able to detect code like `arr[1]` as an template dependency). To workaround this, if object property (`theValues[0].data` in your code) is accessed, it checks whether the value is array and if yes **it iterates the whole array (plus all nested arrays)** [to mark the items as dependencies](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/edf7df0c837557dd3ea8d7b42ad8d4b21858ade0/src/core/observer/index.js#L268) - you can read more in depth explanation [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6284)

One solution to this problem is to create local variable `let data = theValues[0].data` as tony19 suggests. Now the `.data` Vue getter is not called every time and the performance is fixed...

But if your data is immutable (never change), just use `Object.freeze()` and Vue will not try to detect changes of such data. This will not only make your code faster but also saves a [ton of memory](https://reside-ic.github.io/blog/handling-long-arrays-performantly-in-vue.js/) in case of large lists of objects

**Note** that this problem is fixed in Vue 3 as it uses very different reactivity system based on ES6 proxies...

### Tip 2

Although Vue `computed` properties are highly optimized, there is still some code running every time you access the property (checking whether underlying data is dirty and computed prop needs reevaluate) and this work adds up if you use it in a tight loop as in your case...
Try to make local copy of the `theKeys` `computed` prop before executing the loop (shallow copy is enough, no need for a deep copy)

See this [really good video](https://youtu.be/5B66qer8cZo?t=330) from Vue core member

Of course the same issue applies to accessing the `dataForDataTable` computed prop from the template. I encourage You to try to use watcher instead of `computed` to implement same logic as `dataForDataTable` and store it's result in `data` to see if it makes any difference...